# Which Slider control should I use for an asp.net project: Silverlight or Ajax?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, asp.net-ajax, slider

Both Silverlight and Ajax control toolkit offer the Slider control.

Question: **Which one, from your experience, is the better choice?**

My reservation about the Silverlight control is that Silverlight seems to be 'abandoned' by Microsoft [correct me if I am wrong] and I might have to extend the project with additional features in the future.

My reservation about the Ajax control is relative lack of documentation [in comparison with Silverlight].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion silverlight is the best one to use.

For the comparison of both please visit this [link](http://www.slideshare.net/umarali1981/difference-between-ajax-and-silverlight).